# Silverlight 4 application crashing rather than throwing exception

Tags: silverlight-4.0, forms-authentication, wcf-ria-services

I have been using Shawn Wildermuths [example](http://wildermuth.com/2009/12/15/Architecting_Silverlight_4_with_RIA_Services_MEF_and_MVVM_-_Part_1) and it has been working fine no problems at all.  Today, however, I have added a few of my own Models and ViewModels and it still works.  Problem appears when I start to add the attribute `[RequiresAuthentication]` into my `DomainService`.  Although the code has exception handling, it prefers to crash Internet Explorer rather than display the nice `ErrorWindow` that is part of a new Silverlight Business Application.  Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // Remove the ! from the above line
                // etc. 
            }
        }
```

You need to ensure that: if the app is running outside of the debugger, report via a childwindow. :)